# Set $.post value to function

Tags: jquery, function, set

Is it possible to return the value of a jquery post into a normal js function like that ?

```
function get_err(req) {
    var error = $.post("get_err.php", { error: req },
    function(data) { return data; }, "text");
}
```

If I set alert(data); it's working, but i don't need it to be alerted, i need it to be returned so i can use it like here:

```
success: function(data) {
   $("#error").html(get_err(data));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches:

1. Make synchronous request. It is not recommended, so I'll not describe it in more detail
2. Use 'handler' function, like this:

   ```
   $.post("get_err.php", 
       { error: req },
       function(data) {handle_result(data) },
       "text"
   );

   function handle_result(data){
       //do whatever you need with result here
   }
   ```
3. Use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). This is relatively new jQuery feature, and I've not mastered it yet, so I'm not sure about the example.

   ```
   var deferred = $.ajax({/*ajax params here*/});
   deferred.done([handler1, handler2], handler3); //all handlers are chained and invoke one after another
   //at some moment later or on event//
   deferred.resolve(); //this calls the handlers.

   function handler1(data){};
   function handler2(data){};
   function handler3(data){};
   ```

Comment: You need to add extra four spaces when inside list to format the code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thanks for the hint.